# Is Rack::Session::Cookie secure when used with a session_secret?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, sinatra

How secure is the strategy used in which the cookie consists of base64 encoded array content followed by (I believe) a SHA1 hash of that content salted with a long session_secret known only to the server?  The hash is, as I understand it, a signature to prevent the client from tampering with the cookie contents.  Is this system secure?  In particular, could an attacker figure out how to forge the signature without having access to the session_secret?  Are there any other vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) has known vulnerabilities, so if that's what it uses, I wouldn't recommend it. In theory, this can be exploited to forge the signature.

Comment: Oleksi, wouldn't an attack take months on years if the session_secret was sufficiently long and random?  I guess this is the heart of my question.  Also if there is some other types of attacks which stem from the fact that the attacker could create multiple samples of the form SHA1(<known data>+<unknown hash>) = <known cookie value>.